# OAuth and OpenID confusion regarding claims and access

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, identityserver3, openid-connect, identityserver4

I checking how to use IdentityServer4 as I have heard about it a lot. I am trying to make my concepts clear but I am confused:

Access Token: It contains claims that can be used to restrict API access, it contains client info with a token.

Id token: It contains identity info of user, it cannot be used to restrict access to API but it can be used to pass user info just by a token.

I have few questions:

**What is difference between ApiResources and IdentityResources?**

**What is the difference between ApiClaims, ApiScopeClaim and IdentityClaims? And, when and where they are used?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, access tokens do not contain claims.
It is just a JWT token with no claims. You might want to check out the openID specification document. But in short,

Relying Party makes a GET Request to the Token Endpoint which looks something like this:

```
POST /token/HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-url-encoded
Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW

    grant_type=authorization_code&code=xxxxxxxxxx&redirect_URI=https%3A%2F%2Fclient.example.org%2Fcb
```

The identity Server should return a response like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
{
   "access_token": "S1AV32hKG",
   "token_type" : "Bearer",
   "refresh_token": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
   "expires_in": 3600,
   "id_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

As you see the server responds with an access token that can be used to make a  request to the userinfo endpoint which contains claims about the user. Claims are nothing but more information regarding the resource owner.

This should be the userinfo endpoint response:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
 Content-Type: application/json
 {
   "sub": "248289761001",
   "name": "Jane Doe",
   "given_name": "Jane",
   "family_name": "Doe",
   "preferred_username": "j.doe",
   "email": "janedoe@example.com",
   "picture": "http://example.com/janedoe/me.jpg"
  }
```

Read http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#UserInfoRequest for more information

Comment: Basically access token gives you a green pass to retrieve claims or gain access to a resource

Comment: I think,  id token  cannot be sent to request userinfo but it is access token? The resources access can be set by access token not by id token!

Comment: UserInfo Request (Can be a GET or a POST)

GET /userinfo HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Authorization: Bearer XXXXAccessTokenXXXX 

It is access token that is sent to the user info endpoint. It was a typo, corrected it